# Netsuite - Workflow to have pop up appear on button click is not working

Tags: netsuite

I have a workflow set up in Netsuite which adds a button (state 1) and when the button is clicked a message is shown. Unfortunately when the button is clicked nothing is popping up.

My workflow is set up as follows:

Sate 1 - Action: Add Button - Trigger on Before Record Load. (This is fine. Button is being added.)

Transition - From State 1 To State 2. All other fields are blank except Execute on Button which has my button - Pop Up.

State 2 - Type is Show Message - Trigger On: Before User Edit. Text is: This is a test.

My end goal is to be able to have a message pop up before an email is sent but cannot get past State 2.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflow Action Show Message is only available on user events like field edit, source etc(i.e you need user action on current record). So, it won't work on button click transition.

You can add button using client script and then on button click use [N/ui/message](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4497735093.html) module to show message to user.